# Elementor not loading with specific theme, Error 500 "Could not laod preview"

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, elementor

I am using premiumpress theme v10.5.8,on wordpress 6.2 and elementor(latest) and when I activate my theme elemntor editor cant be loaded. It gives error The preview could not be laoded and error 500 I already tried safe mode and checked memory limitations but it didnt help. [image]
[image]

**Things I tried:
**Elementor safe mode, and loader mode both didnt work
Changing theme to another one fixes the elementor but I want to use PremiumPress
Disabling All other PLugins
Downgrading WordPress to 6.0.3

Comment: Turn on debug true in config file and solve error

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by downgrading elementor to a previous version, maybe it was a conflict with new version.